# How to report emmeans results when p value = 1.00?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans, glmmtmb, beta-distribution

I am working with data of vegetation cover (proportions) for different height strata (0-5, 5-15, 15-30, >30 cm, and also bare ground) amongst four different sites and two different time periods (breeding and non breeding season).
I want to evaluate the differences between sites (sitio) and seasons (epoca), and went with GLM using the beta distribution (`glmmTMB package`), and then `emmeans`, but I got a few odd p values (p = 1.00).

For example, for bare ground (sd):

```
> beta_sd <- glmmTMB(sd ~ sitio * epoca,
+                    data = vege2,
+                    family = beta_family)
> Anova(beta_sd)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: sd
             Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
sitio       34.364  3   1.66e-07 ***
epoca       11.420  1  0.0007266 ***
sitio:epoca 10.668  3  0.0136613 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> summary(beta_sd)
 Family: beta  ( logit )
Formula:          sd ~ sitio * epoca
Data: vege2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  -154.2   -125.6     86.1   -172.2      167 


Dispersion parameter for beta family (): 7.51 

Conditional model:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -0.83812    0.13737  -6.101 1.05e-09 ***
sitioEC          -0.40416    0.19980  -2.023  0.04309 *  
sitioRE           0.25440    0.19070   1.334  0.18218    
sitioSI          -0.03149    0.19385  -0.162  0.87096    
epocaREP          0.03018    0.24905   0.121  0.90353    
sitioEC:epocaREP  0.37458    0.33078   1.132  0.25746    
sitioRE:epocaREP  0.91047    0.33104   2.750  0.00595 ** 
sitioSI:epocaREP  0.02317    0.33682   0.069  0.94516    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And then I used `emmeans` to check which particular sites differ during each season:

```
> EMM <- emmeans(beta_sd, ~ sitio * epoca)
> EMM
 sitio epoca emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 CB    POST  -0.838 0.137 Inf   -1.1074    -0.569
 EC    POST  -1.242 0.147 Inf   -1.5301    -0.954
 RE    POST  -0.584 0.133 Inf   -0.8445    -0.323
 SI    POST  -0.870 0.138 Inf   -1.1401    -0.599
 CB    REP   -0.808 0.208 Inf   -1.2165    -0.399
 EC    REP   -0.838 0.162 Inf   -1.1557    -0.519
 RE    REP    0.357 0.173 Inf    0.0187     0.695
 SI    REP   -0.816 0.181 Inf   -1.1707    -0.462

Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
> pairs(EMM, by = "epoca")
epoca = POST:
 contrast estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 CB - EC   0.40416 0.200 Inf   2.023  0.1795
 CB - RE  -0.25440 0.191 Inf  -1.334  0.5411
 CB - SI   0.03149 0.194 Inf   0.162  0.9985
 EC - RE  -0.65856 0.197 Inf  -3.338  0.0047
 EC - SI  -0.37267 0.200 Inf  -1.862  0.2447
 RE - SI   0.28589 0.191 Inf   1.496  0.4400

epoca = REP:
 contrast estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 CB - EC   0.02958 0.264 Inf   0.112  0.9995
 CB - RE  -1.16487 0.271 Inf  -4.301  0.0001
 CB - SI   0.00832 0.275 Inf   0.030  1.0000
 EC - RE  -1.19445 0.237 Inf  -5.036  <.0001
 EC - SI  -0.02126 0.242 Inf  -0.088  0.9998
 RE - SI   1.17319 0.250 Inf   4.689  <.0001

Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates
```

The differences I get with `emmeans` are correct, it's the same result I got with other types of analysis. But the p values of 1.00 and 0.99 throw me off, it doesn't feel right to put that on an article. Is it ok to report it that way? Or am I missing something?

Comment: "Is a p-value of 1.00 okay to put in an article?" isn't a programming-related question, so it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Perhaps it could be a better fit for Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange).

Comment: It's true that, say, `CB/POST` and `SI/POST` look very similar, but it's hard to know if anything fishy is going on without seeing more detail. Normally we would expect vegetation cover measures to be *continuously* distributed between 0 and 1 (so that it is extremely unlikely for two categories to have a large number of identical responses), but perhaps your data are grouped for some reason - do you have a 'minimal cover' category (which must be greater than 0 in order to work with a beta model)? Do the observed values of cover tend to cluster around discrete values such as multiples of 5?

Comment: Yes, actually, all the vegetation cover values were recorded as multiples of 5 (0-100, then transformed into proportion).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it at all. It is only the *small* P values that are associated with notable effects. A P of 1 just means you observed hardly any effect at all. BTW, if you actually want to demonstrate that an effect is small, you should use an equivalence test against a suitable threshold. See the help for `summary.emmGrid`.

Comment: Thank you very much!